# Does prefetch data by Apache before serving a SPA site hurt performance?

Tags: php, node.js, apache, performance, architecture

I have this application containing 2 parts:

- User-facing SPA web served by Apache
- NodeJS API server

When a user go to the SPA web, Apache will do authentication and prefetch data for that user by making a POST and a GET request to the API before serving the page. This works fine for normal days, but it is pretty slow when there is a lot of traffic.

Apart from improving the API, I think delegating authentication and data fetching to client-side would improve performance.

My questions are:

- Does prefetch data by Apache before serving the SPA page hurt performance?
- And would it be better to let client-side does the fetching?

Comment: This depends on a number of factors, but usually Apache is not the right location to do these requests. It might be beneficial to instead let Apache hit a dedicated endpoint in your NodeJS service, which returns the application or an error message

Comment: 1) It does affect performance
2) Allowing the the client-side to do the fetching is actually the whole aim of SPA's because having some content on the page while the user waits actually creates the illusion that your page loads fast (while indicating the page is loading)

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should make requests to API directly from your SPA using ajax, then you can store your static files (html, js, css) on [Google Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) or [Amazon EC3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html).

1) Yes, it's bad for performance, because it's unuseful layer between browser and your API. Also default Apache creates new process to handle request, so [it's bad for your RAM](http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/nginx-vs-apache/)

2) Yes it's better and nowadays best practice

Answer (score 1):

Here are my recommendation

**User-facing SPA web served by Apache**

Use Nginx instead. It will be much faster because of a event based web server instead of launching processes

> When a user go to the SPA web, Apache will do authentication and prefetch data for that user by making a POST and a GET request to the API before serving the page. This works fine for normal days, but it is pretty slow when there is a lot of traffic.

If this happens only for the first call then you have to take a call on your end. Basically you have `1` request which on server translates to `2` sub request. So you have total `3` requests.

Now if a client refreshes the page and you still fetch the information then it a bad design.

Also doing things on webserver would mean you have less flexibility in testing changes, tomorrow if you want to change approach, every time you need to update your config and reload the server

> Does prefetch data by Apache before serving the SPA page hurt performance?

Yes it does. You increase the load on server and you can have better control of things at client side.

> And would it be better to let client-side does the fetching?

Yes, you can add client side and server side caching separately to make system even more performant.

But this all becomes a opinion based approach. So you should use approach that is able to server your purpose